# Variable thread safety and lock keyword

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I'm writing C# application with typical scenario in which multiple threads use a local variable. I tried to be smart and instead of plainly using *lock* keyword, I came with following class:

```
public class LockedVariable<T>
{
    T innerValue;
    object lockObj;
    public LockedVariable(T obj)
    {
        innerValue = obj;
        lockObj = new object();
    }


    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            lock (lockObj)
            {
                return innerValue;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            lock (lockObj)
            {
                this.innerValue = value;
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

After that, I started doubting a few things about it:

1. It's easy to use but will it even work correctly? Maybe it's not thread safe at all and would be only if I surrounded every reference to this class with *lock* keyword?
2. Maybae somewhere in .NET framework there already is equivalent of such a class?
3. What is the worst thing that can happen if multiple threads try to access the sample local variable (in my case variable of value type like simple Int32, bool, enumeration , etc.)? Will my application crash (throw an exception) right in the moment when two threads try to access the same variable, or what?
4. (related to 3) What if this is a writer-reader scenario (one thread change's variable's value, the other reads it). May not using the *lock* keyword crash the application, or the worst thing that can happen is that the reader thread will see outdated value?

Comment: Simultaneous access *per se* does not crash the application. The result is that some thread is going to read wrong data, for various definitions of "wrong." If that data happens to be mission critical, and the kind of "wrong" is bad enough, the thread may subsequently crash when trying to use the invalid data.

Comment: No, this kind of fine-grained locking almost never works.  It does absolutely nothing to ensure that a thread has a consistent view of the class object that contains a member of this class.  And since T is usually a class, it does absolutely nothing at all since object reference updates are already atomic.  It only gives a false sense of reliability, don't use it.

Comment: Imagine that somewhere, the declaration `LockedVariable<int> t = new LockedVariable<int>(0);` appears. Now, imagine two threads run the update `t.Value = t.Value + 1;`. Just protecting the individual reads and writes doesn't prevent the end result being `1`, because both threads did their reads, then both did their additions, then both did their writes.